# Error When Trying to Use MAX() Aggregate Function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12.1

I am using a query with a pivot to avoid multiple rows, but still getting multiple rows.

### Query

```
SELECT B1_ALT_ID, SERV_PROV_CODE, CERTIFICATE_NUMBER, DIF_CATEGORY, B1_SHORT_NOTES, REC_DATE
FROM ACCELA.B1PERMIT A
JOIN BCHCKBOX B
ON A.B1_PER_ID1 = B.B1_PER_ID1
AND A.B1_PER_ID3 = B.B1_PER_ID3
AND( B.B1_CHECKBOX_DESC = 'Certificate Number' OR B.B1_CHECKBOX_DESC = 'DIF_Category' )
JOIN BPERMIT_DETAIL C
ON C.B1_PER_ID1 = B.B1_PER_ID1
AND C.B1_PER_ID3 = B.B1_PER_ID3
PIVOT(
    MAX( B.B1_CHECKLIST_COMMENT )
    FOR B1_CHECKBOX_DESC IN (
        'Certificate Number' AS CERTIFICATE_NUMBER,
        'DIF_Category' AS DIF_CATEGORY
    )
)
WHERE( B1_ALT_ID LIKE 'DIF2%' OR B1_ALT_ID LIKE 'DIF1%' );
```

### Current Result

[image]

### Desired Result

[image]

To avoid the multiple rows, I tried using the MAX() aggregate function:

```
SELECT B1_ALT_ID, SERV_PROV_CODE, CERTIFICATE_NUMBER, DIF_CATEGORY, B1_SHORT_NOTES, MAX( REC_DATE )
FROM ACCELA.B1PERMIT A
JOIN BCHCKBOX B
ON A.B1_PER_ID1 = B.B1_PER_ID1
AND A.B1_PER_ID3 = B.B1_PER_ID3
AND( B.B1_CHECKBOX_DESC = 'Certificate Number' OR B.B1_CHECKBOX_DESC = 'DIF_Category' )
JOIN BPERMIT_DETAIL C
ON C.B1_PER_ID1 = B.B1_PER_ID1
AND C.B1_PER_ID3 = B.B1_PER_ID3
PIVOT(
    MAX( B.B1_CHECKLIST_COMMENT )
    FOR B1_CHECKBOX_DESC IN (
        'Certificate Number' AS CERTIFICATE_NUMBER,
        'DIF_Category' AS DIF_CATEGORY
    )
)
WHERE( B1_ALT_ID LIKE 'DIF2%' OR B1_ALT_ID LIKE 'DIF1%' );
GROUP BY B1_ALT_ID, SERV_PROV_CODE, CERTIFICATE_NUMBER, DIF_CATEGORY, B1_SHORT_NOTES
```

But I got the error:

```
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
```

I went to the Oracle docs and read the error is caused when using an aggregate function without the GROUP BY clause, but I'm using it. How can I avoid the error and not get multiple rows?

I'm using Oracle version 12.1.

Comment: I assume you won't have an error if you wrap this around your original query. i.e. `SELECT B1_ALT_ID, SERV_PROV_CODE, CERTIFICATE_NUMBER, DIF_CATEGORY, B1_SHORT_NOTES, MAX( REC_DATE ) FROM ([full original query]) a GROUP BY B1_ALT_ID, SERV_PROV_CODE, CERTIFICATE_NUMBER, DIF_CATEGORY, B1_SHORT_NOTES`, but why would getting the `max(REC_DATE)` remove your duplicate rows? `CERTIFICATE_NUMBER` and `DIF_CATEGORY` are different.

Comment: Error found: I had a semicolon after the WHERE clause. I posted my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up answering my own question. It turns out the error was caused because I left the semicolon after the WHERE cause, which is why Oracle was complaining I didn't have a GROUP BY clause. My fixed query:

```
SELECT B1_ALT_ID, SERV_PROV_CODE, MAX( CERTIFICATE_NUMBER ), MAX( DIF_CATEGORY ), B1_SHORT_NOTES, REC_DATE
FROM ACCELA.B1PERMIT A
JOIN BCHCKBOX B
ON A.B1_PER_ID1 = B.B1_PER_ID1
AND A.B1_PER_ID3 = B.B1_PER_ID3
AND( B.B1_CHECKBOX_DESC = 'Certificate Number' OR B.B1_CHECKBOX_DESC = 'DIF_Category' )
JOIN BPERMIT_DETAIL C
ON C.B1_PER_ID1 = B.B1_PER_ID1
AND C.B1_PER_ID3 = B.B1_PER_ID3
PIVOT(
    MAX( B.B1_CHECKLIST_COMMENT )
    FOR B1_CHECKBOX_DESC IN (
        'Certificate Number' AS CERTIFICATE_NUMBER,
        'DIF_Category' AS DIF_CATEGORY
    )
)
WHERE( B1_ALT_ID LIKE 'DIF2%' OR B1_ALT_ID LIKE 'DIF1%' )
GROUP BY B1_ALT_ID, SERV_PROV_CODE, B1_SHORT_NOTES, REC_DATE;
```

Comment: :) It happens to everyone from time to time ...

Comment: Glad for you you fixed it, but I voted to close this question as typo

Answer (score 0):

If your first query gives the result as stated then try doing aggregation outside of it:

```sql
SELECT 
    B1_ALT_ID, 
    SERV_PROV_CODE, 
    Max(CERTIFICATE_NUMBER) "CERTIFICATE_NUMBER", 
    Max(DIF_CATEGORY) "DIF_CATEGORY", 
    B1_SHORT_NOTES, 
    REC_DATE
FROM
    (
        SELECT B1_ALT_ID, SERV_PROV_CODE, CERTIFICATE_NUMBER, DIF_CATEGORY, B1_SHORT_NOTES, REC_DATE
        FROM ACCELA.B1PERMIT A
        JOIN BCHCKBOX B
        ON A.B1_PER_ID1 = B.B1_PER_ID1
        AND A.B1_PER_ID3 = B.B1_PER_ID3
        AND( B.B1_CHECKBOX_DESC = 'Certificate Number' OR B.B1_CHECKBOX_DESC = 'DIF_Category' )
        JOIN BPERMIT_DETAIL C
        ON C.B1_PER_ID1 = B.B1_PER_ID1
        AND C.B1_PER_ID3 = B.B1_PER_ID3
        PIVOT(
            MAX( B.B1_CHECKLIST_COMMENT )
            FOR B1_CHECKBOX_DESC IN (
                'Certificate Number' AS CERTIFICATE_NUMBER,
                'DIF_Category' AS DIF_CATEGORY
            )
        )
        WHERE( B1_ALT_ID LIKE 'DIF2%' OR B1_ALT_ID LIKE 'DIF1%' )
    )
GROUP BY
    B1_ALT_ID, 
    SERV_PROV_CODE, 
    B1_SHORT_NOTES, 
    REC_DATE
```